# How to add data in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, yaml, hector

I am writing simple java program to insert data into Cassandra. Can it be done through java code only using hector APIs ? or does it require yaml file to be loaded from jconsole ?

I am using cassandra 0.8.5 and when i do jsoncole i do not see load from yaml operation there.

Hence searching for a way to load schemas as well as data from java program into cassandra.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly insert data through java code using Hector. However, in order to do so, you need an instantiated schema.

In previous Cassandra versions (0.6.x branch) the schema was specified in the YAML, you can still do that in the current version. However, recent Cassandra versions support dynamic schema creations which can be done through Java code in hector.

Have a look at [hector-examples](https://github.com/zznate/hector-examples). The [SchemaManipulation](https://github.com/zznate/hector-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/riptano/cassandra/hector/example/SchemaManipulation.java) example demonstrates how to create a simple schema through hector. The Insert* examples demonstrate how to insert data.

Comment: Technically, in 0.6 the schema was specified with an XML file. In 0.7, it could be loaded from a YAML file one time, but you had to change it through the CLI or other dynamic methods after that.  In 0.8 and later, you must use the CLI or other dynamic methods -- there is no longer any type of "schema file".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CLI to set the schema as well as load data; useful for experimenting, etc. until you dive in with higher level clients and even then, the CLI is very useful for resetting schema, adding test data, etc.

Wiki has great information:

- http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli
- http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions